# call function periodically based on yml file setting. (heroku proof)

Tags: ruby, heroku, cron, job-scheduling, rufus-scheduler

I am working on an App that will read a list of rss feeds (stored in yaml file) and sends a message to Hipchat when there is a new item in that feed.

Here is the structure of my feeds.yml file.

```
feeds:
  feed_name:
    url:
    poll_interval: 30 #in seconds
    hipchat_room: 
    hipchat_color:
    hipchat_from:
    hipchat_nofiy:
```

I want each feed to have a different poll interval (the time that the system will check for new items.)

My question is: How do I handle the poll interval in the code. Each time that interval is reached I need to call the method to process the feed and that time can be different from feed to feed.
Should I use something like rufus-scheduler gem?

I want my app to be simple and be able to run in the Heroku Free tier without problems.

Thank you.

**Edit:** I dont have much code yet. I am just planning the application. I am thinking like this:

**app.rb**

```
# reads the feeds
feeds_list = YAML.load(File.read("feeds.yml"))

# iterates each feed and creates a feed object.
feeds_list['feeds'].each do |f|   
    feed = HipchatRssNotify::Feed.new f

    # calls some method to process that particular feed. 
    # The call should be called periodically based on the feed poll_interval.
    feed_processor.process(feed)
 end
```

I think I could rufus-scheduler gem but I am not sure how heroku will handle it if I have many feeds. The gem would create one thread for each feed if I understood correctly.

Comment: It's difficult to say how you handle the poll interval, because we can't see the code you've written.

Comment: Updated post with sample code.

Comment: Rufus-scheduler, by default, has a pool of max 77 work threads. These work threads are used to run triggered jobs. So, if you schedule less than 78 feeds at one time, the "one thread for each feed" will be true.